# Rails long running controller action and scaling to 500-1000 requests per second

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, concurrency, puma

I'm currently trying to optimize and scale an API built on Ruby on Rails behind an AWS ALB that sends traffic to NGINX and then into Puma to our Rails application. Our API has a timeout option of 30 seconds maximum which is when we eventually timeout the request. Currently we have a controller action that queues a Sidekiq worker and then we poll a Redis key every 100ms for the first 1 second and then move to polling every 500ms for the remaining 29 seconds. Many of our requests can be completed in under 1 second, but some of them will take the full 30 seconds before they succeed or timeout, telling the user to retry in a little while.

We're currently trying to load test this API and scale it to 500-1000 RPS and we're running into problems where the slower requests will block up all of our connections. When a slow request is running shouldn't Puma be able to take other requests in during the sleep period of the slow requests?

If this was not an API we could easily just immediately respond after we queue the background worker, but in this case we need to wait for the response and hold the connection for up to 30 seconds for the  API request.

Comment: The DB connection is claimed by the worker and released back to the pool when the job finishes. You can try releasing the connection before doing some long operation like an http request.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that you can have multiple redis queues and push specific tasks to certain queues.

If you have a queue for the quick tasks and a queue for the slower tasks, then both can run in parallel without the slow tasks holding everything else up.